# Admob telling me show test ads on release build

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to release a new version of my app.
The older version can still display ads, but my newer version (release build, not debug)
cannot show ads. I am getting the following error:

```
2020-03-03 01:54:42.351 7098-7098/? I/Ads: Use RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("457B729F085881806B918663EF07468C") to get test ads on this device.
2020-03-03 01:54:42.442 3275-7238/? W/Ads: App does not have the required permissions to get location
2020-03-03 01:54:42.517 3275-7485/? I/Ads: SDK version: afma-sdk-a-v20088999.19649000.1
2020-03-03 01:54:43.174 7098-7098/? I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3
```

Any way to tell the Admob SDK that the current build is a release build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: just wait for some hours till people start downloading and using the app.

Actually the log messages don't mean that I had to run test ads. It seems admob was not just showing ads until some people downloaded my app and started using it.
Once I published the update, I had to wait for 6-7 hours after which ads started showing.

Answer (score 2):

one more step you can do,
as you see in your log this code  `Use RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("457B729F085881806B918663EF07468C") to get test ads on this device.`

with your device id is: `457B729F085881806B918663EF07468C`

now before intilization you can add the following:

```
RequestConfiguration configuration = new RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("457B729F085881806B918663EF07468C")).build();
MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(configuration);
```

any body else reading this solution should change the device ID.

reference [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads)